# Reduction of data that resides in shared memory when size is not a power of 2

Tags: arrays, sum, cuda, reduction, gpu-shared-memory

I am working on a CUDA project and I can't figure out how to reduce an array when its size isn't a power of 2.

There are many problems related to this on SO, however in my case the kernel has already been launched with a 2D block and 2D grid launch configuration and the array is in **shared memory**. I don't think padding is a option since the array has a size of 280 to 300 elements and I would have to pad up to 512 elements.

Is there any efficient algorithm for this?

Comment: Please use search before posting questions (it is also done for you when you try to create a question). Mandatory reading: [Optimizing Parallel Reduction in CUDA by Mark Harris](http://www.cuvilib.com/Reduction.pdf) [PDF], reduction samples in CUDA toolkit.

Comment: If cuda version of gpu doesn't meet required version for @Drop's advice, you can use just 100 threads to sum 300 values into 100, then use 25 threads to sum 100 values into 25, then use 5 threads to sum 25 values into 5 then sum remaining 5 values by single thread and put non-used threads iinto other uses such as initializing some arrays of next kernel or something else.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik This ancient presentation assumes G80 GPU that is the very first CUDA-capable GPU (compute v1.0). There is no technical possibility to not meed the requirement.

Comment: @Drop I posted this after going through that pdf and  there in all the examples the number of elements in shared memory is power of 2. But in my case its not.

Comment: @AliyaClark Please read the [deduplication link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048895/reduce-in-cuda-for-arbitrary-number-of-elements) carefuly

Comment: spin up however many threads you want, in whatever configuration you want.  Test each thread against the size of the data set.  If the thread corresponds to valid data, have it load valid data.  If the the thread does not correspond to valid data, have it load zero.  Otherwise the reduction approach is identical to any of the other methods you have studied and come across.

Comment: @drop went through whole code and there as I understood number of elements in the global array is not power of 32 but in all the examples the number of elements loaded to shared memory is power of 2. I think there is no solution other than padding with zeros. correct me if I have missed something in there

Comment: @Robert For example if no of elements is 280 would it better to reduce it to 256 sequentially using a loop and then reducing as given in the examples. Because otherwise I'll have to load up to 512 elements.

Comment: This is such a trivial little problem that I would not waste time worrying about it.  A thread block of 256 threads with a loop of up to 2 iterations should be fine.